# How to create a calendar of sum values based on first and end dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, sum, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with the following constitution :

```
    Name             First_date        End_date            Value
1   AAA         2022-06-18 00:00:00 2022-06-18 20:00:00      20
2   BBB         2022-06-19 14:00:00 2022-06-19 16:00:00      40
87  CCC         2022-06-18 04:00:00 2022-06-20 04:00:00      60
0   DDD         2022-06-18 00:00:00 2022-06-20 23:00:00      60
93  EEE         2022-06-26 05:30:00 2022-06-26 15:30:00      35
91  FFF         2022-06-18 00:00:00 2022-06-26 23:00:00      32
230 GGG         2022-06-18 00:00:00 2022-07-02 00:00:00      36
4265    HHH         2022-06-18 00:00:00 2022-07-02 18:00:00  40
```

I have another empty dataframe in which I have all hour from today's date (2022-06-18 00:00:00) and the 2023-01-01 in columns (4705 columns).

For each column, I need to report in rows the value if the date of the column is included between first and end date of the first. The name will be report in index of the row.

See :

```
Index            2022-06-18 00:00:00 2022-06-18 01:00:00 2022-06-18 02:00:00    ...
AAA              20                  20                  20
BBB              0                   0                   0
CCC              0                   0                   0
DDD              60                  60                  60
EEE              0                   0                   0
FFF              32                  32                  32
GGG              36                  36                  36
HHH              40                  40                  40
```

I tried some things with the groupby function and agg(sum) but I can not achieve my point by myself.

Comment: Could you show the sample of desired output in table format like your sample data?  it is easier to picture that way than just a description.

Comment: Done @Emma , I tried to make it clear